# Method as to grouping columns by a unique value in a pandas dataframe WITHOUT changing their data-types. PANDAS GROUPBY

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

I am struggling to find a method which will group by data frame by unique values.

If I type in

```
products = q3_df.groupby(['product_id']).agg(['unique']).reset_index()
```

This will return a multi-index column. The data types have changed so I cannot run the sort function.

```
products.sort_values(by=[('Price x Quantity', 'unique')], ascending = False)
```

This returns an error because the values have all changed to tuples.

If I try:

```
products.q3_df.groupby(['product_id']).nunique().reset_index()
```

This will change the values of Price x Quantity to an integer and count the number of unique values which is not what I want.

I want to groupby unique product_id and then sort by Price x Quantity to get the top 10 highest selling products, without changing the values of the Price x Quantity column.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the error ? and can you provide the sample of df ?

Comment: as @Bushmaster commented, it will be really helpful if you provide a sample of the dataframes you are using because otherwise, it's difficult to reproduce the problem you're running into. you can copy and paste the output from `q3_df.head().to_dict()` directly into your question, thanks!